# Integer c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, int, wrapper

I'm doing a very small and simple Integer class wrapper in C++, which globaly looks like this:

```
class Int
{
  ...
private:
  int value;
  ...
}
```

I handled almost all the possible assignements, but I don't find out what kind of operator I have to use to get native left assignement.

eg:

```
Int myInteger(45);
int x = myInteger;
```

Comment: There's no assignment there. The default copy constructor will handle that.

Comment: @chris the second line initializes a plain `int`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Oh, I could have sworn that was a capital I, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want a conversion operator to convert to int:

```
class Int
{
 public:
  operator int() const { return value; }
 ...
};
```

This allows the following initialization of an `int`

```
int x = myInteger;
```

In C++11, you can decide whether you restrict that conversion to `int`, or whether you allow further conversions from `int` to something else. To restrict to `int`, use an `explicit` conversion operator:

```
explicit operator int() const { return value; }
```

although it is probably not necessary in this case.